# ruby - delete all the files in the directory

Tags: ruby, file

I've create a csv file in directory and now in some other action in my controller I'm reading that file and code it, then close the file and finally delete that file in directory. while deleting I'm Getting the error "Permission denied @ apply2files"

```
dir_path = "path_to_dir/"
file = "myfile.csv"

csv_file = File.open("#{dir_path}/#{file}", "r")

# Code...

csv_file.close
Delete the file in directory
```

I've used many method but all of them giving me same error

```
# First Method
Dir.glob("#{dir_path}").each do |file|
    File.delete(file)
end

# Second Method
Pathname.new(dir_path).children.each { |p| p.rmtree }

# Third Method
Dir.foreach(dir_path) {|f| File.delete("#{dir_path}/#{f}") if f != '.' && f != '..'}

#  Fourth Method
if File.directory?(dir_path)
    Dir.foreach(dir_path) do |file|
        if ((file.to_s != ".") and (file.to_s != ".."))
            self.deleteFilesInDirectory("#{dir_path}/#{file}")
        end
    end
    Dir.delete(dir_path)
else
    File.delete(dir_path)
end
```

All of them giving me same error

Can anyone help me to delete all files from a specific directory?

Comment: _"Permission denied"_ – seems like your file system permissions don't allow it. Do you (or the Ruby process) have write permission for the file / directory?

Comment: That sounds like a file permission issue. How are you creating the file?

Comment: stat the files from the command line, and report the file permissions in your post. You can alter usernames or paths if you need to redact something sensitive, but you can't get help without real data about permission settings, inherited permissions, hidden attributes, and OS.

Comment: This is the status of the file while i did try to delete that same file on the rails console

`#<File::Stat
 dev=0x0,
 ino=1970324836974643,
 mode=0100666 (file rw-rw-rw-),
 nlink=1,
 uid=0,
 gid=0,
 rdev=0x0,
 size=2127986,
 blksize=nil,
 blocks=nil,
 atime=2022-04-26 10:55:30.264869 +0530 (1650950730), 
 mtime=2022-04-26 10:50:50.0065784 +0530 (1650950450),
 ctime=2022-04-25 16:59:40.5235991 +0530 (1650886180)>`

Did anyone understand from the status why it's giving me the permission denied error while deleting the file